# Does the Kimberling sequence map numbers "arbitrarily far away"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

The [Kimberling sequence](http://oeis.org/A007063) is a recursively defined "shuffling sequence" (pictorial description [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67542/the-kimberling-sequence)). Let $k:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be the Kimberling sequence. Does $k$ map members of $\mathbb{N}$ arbitrarily far away, or more formally: given $N\in\mathbb{N}$ is there $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|k(m)-m|>N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Indeed, as noted at [A007063](http://oeis.org/A007063), 
$$k(\theta_j)=3\theta_j-(j+1),
$$
where 
$$\theta_j:=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}2^{\lfloor i/3\rfloor}\ge2^{\lfloor(j-1)/3\rfloor}. 
$$
So,
$$k(\theta_j)-\theta_j=2\theta_j-(j+1)\underset{j\to\infty}\longrightarrow\infty,
$$
as desired.